# How do align text vertical in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I like to know, how to align text vertical in Text Widget. There is an attribute called textAlign. It will align the text center of both vertical and horizontal. So I need to algin text only in vertical.

When I set TextAlign.center,

[image]

Comment: You means you want show text like first H then in new line W so on...

Answer (score 1):

The Text widget can be aligned in some parent widget (eg. [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html), [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) etc). Or you may wrap Text with [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Row() Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) or [Column()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) and use their `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignment` for alignment of the widget

```
Column(
  crossAixsAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[ Text() ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**wrap your text inside a Align widget,**

**so you can control the alignment in any direction horizontal or vertical or both**

[image: see result]

```
Container(
        height: 48,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.blue)),
        child: const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            'Hello World',
          ),
        ),
      ),
```